# Can't get broom package exports with getFromNamespace()

Tags: r, broom

I have a function that is attempting to get a specific 'tidier' from the broom package. getFromNamespace, however, cannot find them. Consider the reprex below:

```r
f <- function(tidier = c("tidy", "glance", "augment")) {
  tidier_func <- match.arg(tidier)
  tidier_func <- utils::getFromNamespace(tidier_func, "broom")
  tidier_func(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))
}

f("tidy")
#> Error in get(x, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE): object 'tidy' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is this error related to broom's modelgenerics offshoot? S3?

Comment: It looks like it works if you specifically ask for the tidier for lm objects, a la `f("tidy.lm")` after changing the `tidier` options. Depending on what you are doing, maybe this is a work around?

Comment: @aosmith that works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aosmith mentioned, you have to specify the generics.

For lm:

```r
f <- function(tidier = c("tidy", "glance", "augment")) {
  tidier_func <- paste0(match.arg(tidier), ".lm")
  tidier_func <- utils::getFromNamespace(tidier_func, "broom")
  tidier_func(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))
}

f("tidy")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)    37.3      1.88      19.9  8.24e-19
#> 2 wt             -5.34     0.559     -9.56 1.29e-10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For chisq.test:

```r
fchisq <- function(tidier = c("tidy", "glance", "augment")) {
  tidier_func <- paste0(match.arg(tidier), ".htest")
  tidier_func <- utils::getFromNamespace(tidier_func, "broom")
  x <- chisq.test(c(A = 20, B = 15, C = 25))
  tidier_func(x)
}

fchisq("glance")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   statistic p.value parameter method                                  
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                                   
#> 1       2.5   0.287         2 Chi-squared test for given probabilities
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Etc.